# Ansible ignores ansible_ssh_extra_args in inventory or group_vars

Tags: ansible

I am trying to make ansible connect to a machine in the local network which needs some extra options passed in SSH invocations. I tried ansible_ssh_extra_args in inventory, group vars, host vars but it is ignored. Here is an example of my inventory file:

```
[dev]
192.168.10.15

[dev:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file="keys/deploy-myserver"
ansible_ssh_extra_args="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
ansible_ssh_user="deploy"
```

How can I make ansible SSH connections to a specific host use my own custom SSH options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those were added for 2.0, so unless you're running the beta, they won't work yet...

Comment: I really like Ansible as an idea but I find it a bit rough around the edges. The documentation should indicate that this facility is not available in the current release...